# Animate Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a square moving left and right using Interval and Animate.
I can't understand how can i stop that Interval maybe some one can help me.
Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Right = true;
    var div = $("div");
    var Inter;

    $("#Start").click(function () {
        Inter = setInterval(function () {
            if (Right) {
                Right = false;
                div.animate({
                    left: '900px'
                }, "slow")
            } else {
                Right = true;
                div.animate({
                    left: '0px'
                }, "slow")
             }
      });
   });

   $("#Stop").click(function () {
    clearInterval(Inter);
   });
});
```

Comment: `clearInterval` doesn't work or what? Show you html code or post a link to jsfiddle

Comment: no timeInterval specified in `setInterval`

`Inter` will be undefined.

`div.stop()` will do you job

Comment: Here is my HTML code:
`code`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
  <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="animate.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button id="Start">Start</button>
 <button id="Stop">Stop</button>
  <div id="moving"></div>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: you dont need setInterval if you are using jquery element.animate. use element.stop instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify a time interval with `setInterval`. Without it, your interval won't be defined as browsers generally have a minimum and enforced interval requirement. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Right = true;
    var div = $("div");
    var Inter;

    $("#Start").click(function() {
      Inter = setInterval(function() {
        if(Right) {
            Right = false;
            div.animate({left:'900px'},"slow");
        } else {
            Right = true;
            div.animate({left:'0px'},"slow");
        }
      }, 500);
    });

    $("#Stop").click(function() {
        clearInterval(Inter);
    };
});
```

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, you can stop the animation using `div.stop()`; That would look something like this:

```
$("#Start").click(function() {
  if(Right) {
      Right = false;
      div.animate({left:'900px'},"slow");
  } else {
      Right = true;
      div.animate({left:'0px'},"slow");
  }
});

$("#Stop").click(function() {
    div.stop();
};
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it! Make sure you hit the checkmark under my answer to accept it. :-)